# What is the default value of an NSUInteger in local scope?

Tags: objective-c, int, nsinteger

Given the following snippet:

```
- (void)doSomething
{
    NSUInteger count;
}
```

What is count? Is it guaranteed to be 0?

Comment: Thanks everyone. I actually figured it would be garbage memory but explicitly asked if it was guaranteed to be 0. Because I figured that would be more useful to the next person who found this question.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No, it isn't guaranteed to be zero, since it's a local automatic variable. Without initialization, its value is indeterminate. If you want it to be zero, either initialize it:

```
NSUInteger count = 0;
```

or define it as `static`:

```
static NSUInteger count;
```

since variables with static storage duration are implicitly intialized to zero, but note that this has side effects (namely the value persists between function calls).